# Be sure iOS application have received data?

Tags: ios, notifications, server-side

We have been developing a communication application for **iOS**. 
We need be sure an application received data *(message)* by web socket or **push-notification** *(I am not a iOS-developer, but as know an application may not received data if it not on top)*.

I am backend-developer and I am trying resolve it on server side - duplicate a message if server don't receive confirmation *(by API)*. However it overly complicated code on the server. I think it's not right way.

Maybe an application must ask server about change state?

I will be glad see all suggestions?

PS: it's not a chat application. Notifications are using for service functions and user notification.

Comment: What protocol are you using to build chat backend ?? XMPP ?? Using anythird party frameworks ??? Pushers or anything like that

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, It's not chat application. It's use voip for voice but server  send many notifications for information user about order state. Very important  to receive notification for correct showing info and manage state.

Comment: APNS is a best effort service which means you can never be confident that all the messages will be delivered neither apple takes the responsibility of it :) Your best would be to ask your client app developer to contact server everytime user launches the app and know the status of order and update the same in their app :)

Comment: Push are not reliable, the app should send some kind of ACK to your server